# how do u get the last character of the last string in java?

Tags: java, string, arguments, character

I need to get the last character of the last input string. I wrote a piece of code that gets the last letter of the first string:

```
public class LastCharacter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = args[0];
        System.out.println("last character: " + string.substring(string.length() -1)); 
    }
}
```

How can I get the last character of the last string parameter?

Comment: _"i need to get the last character of the last input string"_ Try `String string = args[args.length-1];`, assuming that `args.length >= 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last string will be at `args.length - 1` in the `args` array, since arrays are 0-based in Java. This is also true in general for any array; the last element is always at `array.length - 1`.

So you can do:

```
String lastString = args[args.length - 1];
Character lastCharacter = lastString.charAt(lastString.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

You may try like this:-

```
String str= args[args.length-1];
```

And to get the last character:-

```
char ch = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
```

Comment: That should be `str.length()`; `String` has no public property called `length`.

Comment: @VivinPaliath:- Yes thats correct. Missed that! Updated my answer!

Comment: @VivinPaliath:- Not an issue Sir. Sometimes you do have to pay when you do miss small things just to answer it first!

Comment: (tl;dr: tl;dr.) Sorry, that was my downvote, because I had really thought that the answer missed addressing half of the question when I read it.  It's now a complete answer, so either that was an artifact of voting (too) fast, or I was just tripping.  Unfortunately, I can't undo my vote without a logged edit, which I hadn't realized.  (Sorry--if you were to find an excuse to edit now, I'd clear the downvote.)

Comment: @DavidDuncan:- Not an issue Sir. Although I have edited my answer. If you want you can undo your downvote and possibly give me an upvote ;)

Comment: Fixed; I'll give you the speed bonus, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Int lenght = Args.length;
String s = args[length -1];
```

Thats your last string in the input

Answer (score 1):

I really can't understand the description, but based on the title, I think you want

```
public static void main(String[] args){

      if(args != null && args.length > 0){

              String lastString = args[args.length-1];
              if(lastString.length() > 0){
                    System.out.println(lastString.charAt(lastString.length() - 1));
              }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last string:

```
String last = args[args.length - 1];
```

To get the last character:

```
char c = last.charAt(last.length() - 1);
```